# Migrating MySQL 5.1 to MariaDB 10

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql5.1

I plan on migrating my data from MySQL 5.1 to MariaDB 10.  At the same time I will be upgrading hardware so I will have a completely new server.

Is it possible to simply mysqldump from MySQL 5.1 and import into MariaDB 10?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I haven't tested it, I wasn't sure if there would be issues with the Schema importing and if there was other factors I should consider